# Magnetic Locks On Metal Gate

Tags: magnets

I have a problem with the noise from a magnetic lock on a metal gate. It's a long story, but is it possible to put something between the connectors and have it still work?

Essentially, when the magnet engages it pulls the gate towards the frame from a distance, creating an awful noise. What I want to know is how to make it so that it only really engages when the gate is close to closing. Is this possible?

Any help greatly appreciated. I am at the end of my rope.

Comment: Should be possible.  You will need to figure out what: 1) can be altered while keeping the gate working, and 2) affects the noise you want to change.  One potential may be encasing the "magnet" in your own magnetic field, negating its effect until you want it to activate.

Answer (score 1):

Magnet holding strength will be greatly reduced by any air-gap (or non-ferrous material in the gap) so you want to avoid that. I recommend a small shock-absorber that will slow down the closure but still allow full magnet contact.

[image]

*A quick Google image search found this image. [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JNLJFGX).*

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the gate slamming shut has some metal-to-metal contact happening. I'd look into getting some foam stickytape as used to mount camper shells to pickup truck beds, or as weatherstripping in leaky door frames, and inserting strips of it between the clangy parts of the assembly. It comes in various thicknesses and densities.